# When we integration with Twitter error occurs?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have done twitter integration in Objective-C. I have check before 10 days, It is work perfect. But i have check today then the error occurs. I have attach screenshot. please help me.[image]

Comment: Maybe you included the token in your source code and said token has expired?

Comment: I have used TwitterOAuthViewController for twitter integration. Can you help me where i find the token in my app.